# Highcharts: Failure to render large number of columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart that is displaying *columns* of data, fed in as an array of 2 index arrays.  Those 2 indexes are a label (a string) and a number value.

With less than ~800 columns, highcharts displays this perfectly.  Once more columns than that are fed in, highcharts shows a blank screen, as if there was no data.

Has anyone run in to this issue?  Is it a known issue in highcharts?

Comment: Please post code, so that it will help people to inspect problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase [threshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.threshold) parameter and set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange)